# Twig not rendering HTML tags

Tags: php, symfony, twig

I am using twig as  templating engine and i am facing issue while displaying HTML data.

I searched on SO and got following solution

```
{% autoescape true %} {{ detailArticle.artdesc|raw}} {% endautoescape %}
```

This expression is working on my localhost but giving problem on cPanel the is Live server.

It is not rendering the output. It is displayed as

```
<span style="font-size: 12pt; font-family: 'Times New Roman', serif">.. so on
```

Twig version used is

> "twig/twig": "~1.16",

Please suggest

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You're using `autoescape`, which buffers the contents of that block, and then filters it (escaping HTML entities and so on). If you want to print out a variable that contains markup, use either this:

```
{{ detailArticle.artdesc|raw }}
```

Printing the value as a raw string (no escaping at all), or:

```
{% autoescape false %}
{{ detailArticle.artdesc }}
{% endautoescape %}
```

Which is the same as using `raw` on all variables you're using inside that block

Comment: I tried both. But not working ln live server nd working in locAl xampp. So anythng extra need to be done??

Comment: Twig templates are cached, so you'll probably want to clear the cache on live env. Either run the command, or manually remove the cache files

Comment: And how to remove those. Please let me know as i am trying Twig frst tym

Comment: `app/console cache:clear --env=prod` if you want to/can rely on the SF2 command (can behave unexpected if you're using doctrine, for example). or just `rm -rf app/cache/*` to manually remove the cache. If all you want is to remove the twig cache, then `rm -rf app/cache/prod/twig` should work

Comment: i even shifted to new cPanel, there is no difference even now :( Any ideas please

Comment: I am accepting your answer as you did right ways but actually issue  was with my editor that was used to add content